# Rails associations has_many through instead of HABTM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm fairly new to rails and ActiveRecord and I'm trying to find the correct way to model my data.

I am building an application that let's swim instructors put together a class plan that shows what skills they will be teaching their class and what activities they will use to teach each skill. A Plan can contain many Skills and each Skill can have many Activities associated with it.

On the Plan form there is a widget for the skill-activity combination. In it, user should be able to select a Skill from a dropdown and for the selected skill select multiple activities from a list. This widget can repeat any number of times on the form.

My current model:

```
Class Plan
  has_many :plan_activities
end

Class PlanActivities
  belongs_to :plan
  belongs_to :skill
  has_and_belongs_to_many :activities
end

Class Skill
end

Class Activity
end
```

Is this model correct? My problem with it is that accepts_nested_attribtues_for does not work for HABTM associations. I've read that I can replace it with has_many through:, but that would mean adding yet another join model to the picture. It just seems a little too ugly. Is there a better way to do this?

EDIT:

My Skills and Activities are in list form and I should be able to include the same skill and/or activity on multiple plans.

Comment: I believe relation should be something like this if I understood your requirements correctly. Plan has many activities through skill and skills has many activities..

Comment: Please see my edit. Does your suggestion still work with that?

Comment: Yes it should be possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model is very close. One improvement here would be to completely remove the PlanActivities model. Just have the associations directly on the plan. At this point I don't think the extra model is justified. We have a pretty basic pyramid structure here. At the top is plan with many skills, Each skill has many activities, so a simpler model would look like:

```
class Plan
  has_many :plan_skills
  has_many :activities, through: :plan_skills
end

class Skill
  has_many :activities, through: plan_skills
  has_many :plan_skills

end

class PlanSkill
  belongs_to :plan
  belongs_to :skill
  has_many :activities
end


class Activity
  belongs_to :plan_skill
end
```

The join model is an option but not entirely necessary here. Plan.activities will make the needed join table for you.

Comment: Doesn't this suggest that a particular skill can only be included on one plan? Where as what I want is to be able to create any number of plans that can feature the same skill (You select a skill from a finite list).

For example say I have skills 1,2 and 3. I can have a plan1 with skills 1 and 2, and a plan2 with skills 1 and 3.

Comment: In that case you are correct you would need a join model. See my edit.